Updating nested fields via mongoose
I want to update fields in a user, but I don't know what will come from the request.body
it can be either height/dateOfBirth/address. updating height and dateofbirth works according to tests,address does not being updated. the test fails with result of updatedUser.personalDetails.address.zip being undefined
the schema looks like this:
const updateProfileSchema = {
  body: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      dateOfBirth: { type: 'string', format: 'date' },
      height: { type: 'number' },
      address: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          street: { type: 'string' },
          city: { type: 'string' },
          state: { type: 'string' },
          zip: { type: 'number' },
          country: { type: 'string' },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

the user is like this:
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  personalDetails: {
    height: { type: Number, min: 0 },
    dateOfBirth: { type: Date },
    address: {
      street: String,
      city: String,
      state: String,
      zip: Number,
      country: String,
    },
})

the controller:
const updateProfile = async (request: any, reply: FastifyReply) => {
  const { userId }: { userId : string } = request.user;
  const {
    height,
    dateOfBirth,
    address = {},
  }: {
    height?: number;
    dateOfBirth?: string;
    address?: Record<string, any>;
  } = request.body;

  let user: userType | null;
  try {
    logger.info(`trying to get the user - ${userId}`);
    user = await User.findOne({ _id: userId});
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`can't get the user - ${userId}`, err);
    return await reply
      .status(500)
      .send({ message: 'Getting userfailed, please try again.' });
  }

  if (!user) {
    logger.error(`didn't find user by his id - ${userId}`);
    return await reply
      .status(404)
      .send({ message: 'Could not find user for provided id.' });
  }
  const updatedFields: Record<string, any> = {};

  for (const key in request.body) {
    const value = request.body[key];
    updatedFields[`personalDetails.${key}`] = value;
  }

  try {
    logger.info(`trying updating the user - ${userId}`);
    await User.updateOne(
      { _id: userId},
      { $set: updatedFields },
      {
        runValidators: true,
      },
    );
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`can't update the user - ${userId}`, err);
    return await reply
      .status(500)
      .send({ message: 'Editing user failed, please try again.' });
  }

  return await reply.status(200).send({
    message: 'user updated successfully',
  });
};

the test fails (Jest):
  test('should return 200 when sending address', async () => {
    const address = {
      zip: 29193,
    };

    const res = await supertest(app.server)
      .put(`/api/user/profile`)
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      .send(address);

    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    const updatedUser: userType | null = await User.findOne({
      email: userDetails.email,
    });

    expect(updatedUser).toBeDefined();
    expect(updatedUser?.personalDetails?.address).toBeDefined();
    expect(updatedUser?.personalDetails?.address.zip).toBe(address.zip);
  });


please review the schema definition of User. It has 6 opening brackets but has only 5 closing equivalents. Is it a typo while preparing this post?

typo while preparing the post. the schema is longer I wanted to make it shorter for the relevant fields

To debug, please change the line const address = {
zip: 29193,
}; to const address = {
address:{ zip: 29193 }
};

Thanks I've already fixed it
